# Выбрать все теги внутри body

Tags: javascript

Существует метод, чтобы выбрать **все** теги на странице, внутри body?
Аналог `document.body.innerText` , но для тегов.

Или нужно последовательно проходить всех детей body и проверять их на наличие своих детей? Спасибо!

Comment: нужно выбрать именно все элементы в дом? Или же определенные теги? Если первое, то ничего другого  как рекурсивный обход дерева я не вижу. При этом какая структура выборки должна получиться? Многомерный массив, объект?

Comment: Все элементы в DOM. Структура не важна.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Должно подойти [getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)

`var all = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");`